# Postgresql installation on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, postgresql

I have trouble installing postgresql with apt.

postgresql-9.1 (or postgresql-9.3) installation fails with:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
* Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -l  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log -s -o  -c  config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf" :
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
```

When I try executing `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -l  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log -s -o  -c  config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"`directly, it fails with:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl: undefined symbol: PQping
```

Here is my system information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux daclin 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Would you have any idea on what is going on?

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: check your "data_directory" and make sure that directory is owned by user postgres

Comment: I installed it with `apt-get install postgresql-9.1`

Comment: The data directory is owned by user `postgres`, group `postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found the issue. There was a conflict with libpq.so. It was actually installed twice.

Running `ldconfig -v | grep libpq` showed:

```
libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.1
libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.6
```

I removed the first one and it works like a charm now. The issue was really specific to my setup but it might be helpful anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I had that same setback myself too.  This approach was the one that I used that solved the issue on my end:

We are removing the apt of postgresql that was from the repository.

```
sudo apt-get remove -y --purge postgresql*
```

We then are making source list to download Postgre directly from the company.

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

and add this line to pgdg.list 
for 12.04 or 12.10:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

for 13.04 or 13.10

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main
```

Then ctrl-x as to save the pgdg.list and finally to get out back to command line.
We then grab keys to use this deb package:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Then it'll install the postgresql-9.3.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I had tried that actually (and I retried) but the output was exactly the same.